# How to get value from Object, with default value

Tags: javascript, object

I constantly find myself passing config values to functions accessing them like this:

```
var arg1 = 'test1';
if(isUndefined(config.args.arg1)){
  arg1 = config.args.arg1;
} 

var arg2 = 'param2';
if(isUndefined(config.args.arg2)){
  arg2 = config.args.arg2;
} 

var arg3 = '123';
if(isUndefined(config.args.arg3)){
  arg3 = config.args.arg3;
}
```

where I later use them like this:

```
var url = '<some-url>?id='+arg1+'&='+arg2 +'=' + arg3;
```

Does jQuery/ExtJS or any other framework provide a solution to access variables like this in a simple way, and give variables a default value?

Something like:

```
getValueOfObject(config,'args.arg3','<default>');
```

Or is there maybe a standard solution for this.

**NOTE:**

I was also thinking about the common pattern where you have defaults

```
var defaults = {
   args: {
      args1: ....
   }
   ...
}
```

and doing an object merge.

And then encoding the object to a param String. But as you can see the object **values** also sometimes contain parameter names.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like finally [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) has the [_.get()](https://lodash.com/docs#get) function for this!

Answer (score 113):

Generally, one can use the [or operator](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html) to assign a default when some variable evaluates to falsy:

```
var foo = couldBeUndefined || "some default";
```

so:

```
var arg1 = config.args.arg1 || "test";
var arg2 = config.args.arg2 || "param2";
```

assuming that `config.args` is always defined, as your example code implies.

Comment: I believe it will be ok if `config.args.arg1` is undefined, but  wont this fail if `config` or `config.args` is itself undefined?

Comment: Nope, undefined evaluates to falsy, so the second part of the condition gets assigned to `foo` in such a scenario.

Comment: @karim79 he's implying `config.args.arg1` will throw if `config.args === undefined`

Comment: Well yeah, it won't handle those scenarios, so `config` and `config.args` would need to be checked beforehand.

Comment: Thanks @raynos, that's exactly what I was trying to imply :-)

Comment: @James and @Karim that's exactly what I meant, either `config` or `config.args` could be undefined in my case which would result in a exception thrown ... therefore a function that parses the object graph for a value, in hindsight that a path could be `undefined`

Comment: There's a big flaw here. If `couldBeUndefined = 0`, or any other falsy value, then `foo = "some default"`, instead of getting the desired `foo = 0`

Comment: This will fail, if the value is false. You should do `typeof x.y != 'undefined' ? x.y : "";`

Comment: when arg is boolean and default value is true, everything ruined.

Comment: I used to use this. It recently caused a bug because one of my values was `-0`, took a while to figure out what was causing the bug. It will also fail for empty strings and other stuff which could be valid if unusual data.

Comment: @karim79 Please edit your answer as it is plainly flawed and will cause bugs in peoples' code as has already been point out by Daniel Reina. Leaving it like it is, is irresponsible.

Comment: Note that in more recent JS, you could use `??` over `||` which would match only nullish values, rather than falsey which might address some of the above concerns.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 43):

With ECMAScript 2020 it may be  safer to use [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) than `or` operator.

```
let foo = obj.maybeUndefined ?? "default value";
```

[JS treats 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string ("") as `falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). So, using `or` operator for setting a default value in the following example may cause unexpected results

```
let obj = { maybeUndefined: 0 };
let foo = obj.maybeUndefined || 1; // foo == 1
```

Here, `foo` becomes equal to `1`, when `maybeUndefined` is actually defined. If  `foo` should be assigned a default value only when `maybeUndefined` is actually `undefined` or `null`, then we can use [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```
let obj = { maybeUndefined: 0 };
let foo = obj.maybeUndefined ?? 1; // foo == 0

let obj = {};
let foo = obj.maybeUndefined ?? 1; // foo == 1
```

Answer (score 13):

With ES2018, you can now write `options = { ...defaults, ...options }`:

[Spread syntax - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

> Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects is now possible using a shorter syntax than [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
>
> ```
> const obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };
> const obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };
>
> const clonedObj = { ...obj1 };
> // Object { foo: "bar", x: 42 }
>
> const mergedObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
> // Object { foo: "baz", x: 42, y: 13 }
> ```

Comment: No idea why this was voted down. I gave an upvote FWIW

Answer (score 3):

try `var options = extend(defaults, userOptions);`

This way you get all the userOptions and fall back to defaults when they don't pass any options.

Note use any [`extend`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.extend) implementation you want.

Comment: `extend` usually modifies and returns its first argument. This means you usually want `extend({}, defaults, userOptions)`, so that defaults is not changed.

Comment: Your version of extend may well be immutable, but all the other versions I've come across including the versions from jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), Lodash and  underscore(http://underscorejs.org/#extend) all use the non-immutable form.

Comment: Note: there is also the shortcut `_.defaults` for exactly this purpose.