# How to get "else" in a simplified condition-based operation code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

The original and ugly code:

```js
const lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

if (lang.indexOf("de") == 0)
{
  window.location.href = 'https://gusbemacbe.github.io/suru-plus-folders/de/';
}

# ...

else if (lang.indexOf("es") == 0) 
{
  window.location.href = 'https://gusbemacbe.github.io/suru-plus-folders/es/';
}

else 
{
  window.location.href = 'https://gusbemacbe.github.io/suru-plus-folders/en/';
}
```

I simplified into an elegant condition-based operation:

```js
const lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
const url = 'https://gusbemacbe.github.io/suru-plus-folders/'

function detection(lang) 
{
  let languages =
  {
    'de': () => window.location.href = url+'de',
    'es': () => window.location.href = url+'es',
    'fr': () => window.location.href = url+'fr',
    'it': () => window.location.href = url+'it',
    'nl': () => window.location.href = url+'nl',
    'pt-BR': () => window.location.href = url+'pt-br',
    'pt-PT': () => window.location.href = url+'pt-pt'
  }

  return languages(lang);
}

detection(lang);
```

The problem is `else`, that is for needing to trigger to English if there is not another language into which I didn't translate the website. I checked that I could `return languages(lang) ? 'en': () => window.location.href = url+'en'`, but I am not sure that it is right. I also thought of adding `en': () => window.location.href = url+'en'` to `let languages`, but it needs to be an "`else`".

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `languages[lang]()`? (Otherwise your code won't work even without considering the else)

Comment: Ah, yes, is `languages[lang]()` already an "`else`"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value from Object, with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003999/how-to-get-value-from-object-with-default-value). Something like `return (languages[lang] || languages["en"])()`, assuming you add "en" to the object.

Comment: Do you mean `const lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || 'en': () => window.location.href = url+'en'`?

Comment: Lang code seems to be the same than URLs. Factorize in an array? `url + ([ 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'pt-BR', 'pt-PT' ].includes(lang) ? lang : 'en')`

Comment: @Cid, observe `pt-BR` and `pt-PT` will trigger `pt-br` and `pt-pt`, the window and page regional language codes have different cases (upper and lower).

Comment: @GustavoReis `.toLowerCase()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't Repeat Yourself.

This has a name in programmation: it's the DRY principle. So let's repeat ourselves a bit less here. Click `Run code snippet` to test the function by yourself.

```js
function detectLang(lang) {

  // Let's lowerCase that string to normalize it, so we can compare it with others
  lang = lang.toLowerCase()
  const firstHalf = lang.split('-')[0]

  // A new supported language ? Just add it here.
  const supportedLanguages = ['en', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'pt-br', 'pt-pt']

  // If supportedLanguages contains your language, select it
  const finalLang = supportedLanguages.includes(lang) ? lang
    // Else, check just for the first half
    : supportedLanguages.includes(firstHalf) ? firstHalf
    // Otherwise, fallback to English
    : 'en'

  // Set the URL (uncomment that, that's for the snippet)
  // window.location.href = url + finalLang

  // Return the final lang
  return finalLang
}

console.log("en =>", detectLang("en"))
console.log("fr =>", detectLang("fr"))
console.log("de-DE =>", detectLang("de-DE"))
console.log("pt-PT =>", detectLang("pt-PT"))
console.log("sw =>", detectLang("sw"))
```

This tricky thing, `a ? b : c`, is a [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is basically a one-liner for `if / else`. If `supportedLanguages` has `lang`, it'll execute the corresponding value. If not, it'll try with the first half, or set the language to English. The input is normalized so that the capitalized letters are ignored.

Comment: There is a small problem. I set Germany German as the default language in the browser. The browser detected `de-DE` and triggered to `/en/` instead of `/de/`. Check @georg's comment.

Comment: You're right! Here you go, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Just `de`, `fr` etc in the list is not enough, because `navigator.language` can, and in most cases, will return a full locale code like `de-DE`, `fr-FR` etc. Therefore, you have to check both the full code and then the language id.

You can have a list of supported languages/locales and write a small function like this:

```
const supportedLanguages = new Set([
    'en',
    'de',
    'es',
    'fr',
    'it',
    'nl',
    'pt-br',
    'pt-pt',
]);

function getLanguage() {
    let lang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage).toLowerCase();

    // full locale matches?
    if (supportedLanguages.has(lang))
        return lang;
    
    // language matches?
    lang = lang.split('-')[0];
    if (supportedLanguages.has(lang))
        return lang;

    // no match, return the default
    return 'en';
}
```

The rest is easy:

```
const url = '...'
window.location.href = url + getLanguage()
```

Comment: good use of set.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to repete the code, check out this example..

```
 let lng = {'de':'de',
    'es':'es',
    'fr':'fr',
    'it':'it',
    'nl':'nl',
    'pt-BR':'pt-br'}

function lang(prop){
 let lang = lng.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? lng[prop] : lng['default'];
  console.log(lang)
  window.location.href = url + lang
}
 
lang('es');
```