# How to set default value for Function object?

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to add a default value to a Function object?

```
 function CountOfFruit(bowl){
    this.strawberries = bowl.strawberries
    this.blueberries = bowl.blueberries
    
   if (bowl.strawberries == ""){
     this.strawberries = "there is none"
   }
 }
```

Comment: `this.strawberries = bowl.strawberries == "" ? "there is none" : bowl.strawberries;`??? You could do this in one line using the ternary operator. Or perhaps a default object? - [set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value from Object, with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003999/how-to-get-value-from-object-with-default-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write something like:

```
function CountOfFruit(bowl){
    this.strawberries = bowl.strawberries || "there is none";
    this.blueberries = bowl.blueberries || "there is none";
}
```

In that way, if one of the attributes is null or an empty string, the default value will be used.