# Getting the first true/truthy value in JavaScript/NextJS to use in setting a property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS project using JavaScript, I would like to set the property on a local object.

```
const localItem = 
{
  name: <<here is the value I need to set>>
};
```

However, the data that I am using to set the property may not be reliably complete.
If possible, I'd rather not do a bunch of `if`/`else if` or `switch`/`case` statements since this might be needed for a bunch of properties and I'd like to keep the code compact.

So for the sake of this question/example, let's say that the data that I would like to use is:

```
person.nickname: '', //first choice - if it doesn't exist go to firstName
person.firstName: 'Sammy', //second choice - if it doesn't exist go to 'a default string'
'Mr. Bond' // a default string I presume - use if both of the above are missing
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value from Object, with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003999/how-to-get-value-from-object-with-default-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `||` operators (logical OR) between your options.  Put them in the order you prefer, left to right.

---

So using the data in your question:

```
const person = { nickname: '', firstName: 'Sammy'};

const localItem = 
  {
    name: person.nickname || person.firstName || 'Mr. Bond'
  };

console.log(localItem.name); // Sammy -- it returns the first truthy value
```

Javascript will return the first truthy value; this is an example of [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) – it will stop after the first truthy value and will return the evaluated value of that first truthy value.

If none of your values where truthy, it will return the right most value.

`undefined` or `null` values are fine, they just get passed over – unless they are the last value of all false values; in this case, that `undefined` or `null` is the value that gets passed back to you.

---

Also, if you want to get slightly fancier (you probably just want to stick with the ^ above):

```
const person = { nickname: '', firstName: 'Sammy'};

const localItem = 
  {
    name: [person.nickname, person.firstName, 'Mr. Bond'].find(value=>value)
  };
    
console.log(localItem.name); // Sammy -- it returns the first truthy value
```

In this example, `undefined` or `null` is also okay in your options.

However, if none of the values are truthy, it will return `undefined` (ie. NOT the right most value like in the first example.)

You can read more about the native Javascript find() method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).